# Stop div width from pushing it out of place

Tags: css, html, width, overflow, css-float

I've got 2 divs side by side. One has a fixed with of 150px (sidebar) and one adjusts to the remaining with of the parent div.

```
<div style="margin:0 20%">
    <div style="float:left;width:150px">
        Sidebar contents
    </div>
    <div style="vertical-align:top">
        Main contents
    </div>
</div>
```

When the contents of the "main" div exceed the remaining width, it's expanded and pushed down under the sidebar. How can I stop this without defining a set width for this div (since it's meant to adjust to the parent width)?

Comment: Why not just set a width for both div's and use percentages like 20% for the sidebar and 80% for the main.  And then just float left and right?

Comment: In some browsers, having two widths that add up to 100% won't actually balance them out as it would appear it should. One will be pushed down under the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin-left:150px` for the second div? or use `padding-left:150px` for aligning content

Comment: That won't stop it from going underneath the sidebar

Comment: You can try to find better approach, but I've described most popular.

Comment: I'll just fix the position of the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5TYm2/    here is a working example of something I believe you're looking for.

This is a pretty common way to go about separating content within a wrapping div.

Hope this helps.